# Ng If to false creates empty rows Mat Table Angular

Tags: angular, rows, mat-table

I created a Mat Table with angular, when i put a condition to get only the data i want, it shows me the data i want but also some empty rows which is, i think, the data which dosn't respect the condition.

Here is the table :
[image: Mat table empty rows]

Here is one of the part of the code

```
   <ng-container matColumnDef="NumContrat">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Numéro de contrat </th>
  <ng-container mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
     <ng-container *ngIf="element.DateSignaturePrestataire == null;">
        <td>{{element.NumContrat}} </td>
     </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on stackblitz?

Comment: the `*ngIf` in your example is inside of the container with the `mat-cell` directive, thus rendering an empty entry when it evaluates to `false`

Comment: how can i put the ngif outside de matcell, because i need to use the "element" to call my condition ?

Comment: First remove `;` from the end of `*ngIf` condition like this `*ngIf="element.DateSignaturePrestataire == null"`.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to filter your dataSource Array for this.

- You can use something like this

  > dataSourceArray = dataSourceArray.filter(element=>
  > element.DateSignaturePrestataire != null)

In your code you are simply hiding the data but the row is still present.that is why you are getting those empty rows.In your approach you have to repeat your `ngIf` condition in every row which is not a very good coding practice.

Comment: thank's for your answer, but i got an error : "Type 'String' has no call signatures." when i try to call the filter method

Comment: can you please give me the code of the filter method calling?

Comment: this.dataSource = this.dataSource.filter(element => element.DateSignaturePrestaire == null);

Comment: i'm sorry i'm a begginer in Angular

Comment: in your array does every object has a property of DateSignaturePrestaire ?

Comment: No, DateSignaturePrestaire is an object of dataSource

Comment: https://github.com/clementnguyen31/Security_park/tree/master/src/app/contrats/contrats-list here is my code

Comment: i'm not sure where this error comes from but you try something like this. in your function `getAllData()` try this ` this.dataSource.data = report.filter(element => element.DateSignaturePrestaire == null)`. this shoud work. i think that error comes from you are using `MatTableDataSource` object as your dataSource.Not sure if its the case tho.